# How to get the count number of news as an alias column in MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables (news, seen) and the relation between them is 1 to many: one news has many sees.

I need an SQL Query to get each news with an additional alias column valued by the sum of each news sees.

Here is the structure of the both tables:

---

News:
id_news, news_title, news_text, date, time, pic

Seen: id_seen, id_user, id_news, ip, fulldate, time

---

I need a query that returns the result like:

```
id_news | news_title | news_text |  fulldate   | fulltime | pic   | seen_count (alias)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       | Title Blah | Text Blah | Jun/03/2016 | 19:54:25 | 9.jpg | 934
2       | Title Blah | Text Blah | Jun/01/2016 | 19:24:25 | 6.jpg | 549
```

---

I tried lot of times but really couldn't achieve that.

Comment: Should be able to use `group by` with `count`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select news.*, count(seen.id_seen) as seen_count from news 
left join seen on seen.id_news=news.id_news
group by news.id_news
```

Comment: It really works! Thanks a lot friend! I did some sql like that but without (group by). Please could you just tell me quickly why it should be with group by? :-)

Comment: When you join seen table you have a lot of same records from news table. `group by` make magic and group records from news into one record. It is hard for me to explain it better because I am not English.

Comment: In general `group by ` groups elements with the same value of some field into one.

Comment: Anyway, I got you and thanx for you :-) I O U